# Are Top Gun 2 dogfights & airplane maneuvers real?

Tags: realism, effects, stunts, top-gun-maverick

In the 2nd [trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIgYcrHiTgw) of Top Gun 2, a plethora of swift airplane maneuvers and at least one dogfight take place. **Are those scenes real**, captured by a chase airplane?

Or they're just simulation (Computer Animation)?

Comment: Definitely not.

Comment: A colleague told me that Top Gun's scenes were real, and also fatal for a chase plane pilot. That's why I am asking @Rahul...

Comment: While they did shot few scenes with chase planes and some maneuvers are real. But finally it all comes down to CGI and VFX.

Comment: @Rahul you know this and have references to back you up? Or is this just supposition on your part?

Comment: Let me Google ["Top Gun 2 behind the scenes"](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz9lnIDdkMo) for you.

Comment: Yes, know that I posted the same link under the answer, it makes sense.

Comment: i believe the maneuvers were real for the most part of it while the dogfights were certainly cg trickery

Comment: This question was rather premature. Well, for starters it's not like they could use actual F-14 or Su-57 in flight. They got only partially complete F-14 and Su were completely CGI.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Mostly

According to John Hamm...

> “We’re shooting the movie in, I think, 6K,” Hamm explained (via JoBlo) at the premiere of Amazon’s Good Omens. “So it’s incredibly hi-def. The aerial footage is mind-blowing. And **it’s mostly practical. There’s not a lot of CG. Those guys are really up in planes and getting thrown around in multiple Gs.**”
>
> [**Source**](https://www.comingsoon.net/movies/news/1071309-top-gun-2-jon-hamm-praises-mostly-practical-aerial-sequences)

Comment: What does "Gs" mean?

Comment: G is the expression mean force of Gravity. Standing on the ground we are at 1G, pilots like this can experience 8-9G during dogfighting.

Comment: Oh, it's just the plural of G force, I see. Moreover this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bHt1IbuYgJo backs up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like real airplanes doing real maneuvers, but it looks like there is some camera trickery, editing, and/or post-production effects to amp it up a bit. Camera work can make two planes appear to be closer than they really were; post-production compositing could also make two or more planes appear to come in very close when they were never actually close at all, same for "narrow-miss" explosions.